# How to prevent Emacs from showing passphrase in `M-x shell`?

Tags: shell, passwords

I tried using [attic](https://attic-backup.org) with a passphrase to backup my files from inside `M-x shell`. The shell exposed the passphrase as plain text in the buffer and made it available by typing `M-r` as well as by looking through the shell input history with `C-c C-l`.

When I closed the shell and re-opened the input history, I saw that at least it disappeared. Presumably, because the shell reads it's initial history from `.bash_history` and at least `bash` had the good sense not to write my `passphrase` there.

Do I really need to leave `emacs` to perform my `attic` backups, or is there a way I can configure it not to be careless?

I was able to reproduce the issue with a fresh `emacs -Q` session. I was confused before because Emacs correctly hides the passphrase in all cases except when I call

```
 attic create --stats /path/to/backup::name ~/folders ~/backed ~/up
```

Then `attic` prompts as:

```
Enter passphrase for /path/to/backup::name:
```

The issue can be reproduced with this Python one-liner:

```
python -c 'import getpass; getpass.getpass("Hello")'
```

If the password prompt string is `"Password:"` then Emacs sees a password prompt, but not if the string is anything else.

How can I make Emacs recognize at least attic's password prompts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Shell mode, Emacs detects password prompts based on the prompt. If it sees `Password:` (or `Enter new password:`, or `Passwort:`, or `Wachtwoord:` or a number of variations), it assumes that you're prompted to enter a password and reads a string from the minibuffer (repeating the prompt); this string is not echoed and is not entered in any history list.

If Emacs doesn't recognize a prompt, you can achieve the same effect by calling [`M-x send-invisible`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html#index-send_002dinvisible) (not bound to any key by default).

You can teach Emacs to recognize the password prompts you do see by customizing `comint-password-prompt-regexp`. Note that this regexp is *searched* on the current line, so it should start with `^` if you want to match text at the left margin, and it should end with `\'` if you don't want to allow arbitrary text afterwards.

To add another prompt format, add `\|^…\'` at the end of the existing regexp. For example, you could add this to your init file (remember to double backslashes between double quotes):

```
(setq comint-password-prompt-regexp
      (concat comint-password-prompt-regexp
              "\\|^Enter passphrase for .*:\\s *\\'"))
```

Comment: And if you do add some element to `comint-password-prompt-regexp`, consider submitting it via `M-x report-emacs-bug` so it can be added to the defaults.

Comment: You may need `comint-send-invisible`